# google maps for Flash is deprecated. now what ? which ones is better?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-maps

Since Google has announced that it is [deprecating](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/09/maps-api-for-flash-deprecation.html) [Google Maps for Flash](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/), I am need of some alternatives.

Please elaborate here in order to get the best pick of the maps, since the google maps for flash will be deprecated in next 3 years. Let's get here the best opinions of the peoples - which maps which is build on the Flash platform shall be used instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly insist on using Flash/Flex, look at http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash.

Comment: this is one not bad solution. let see how many out there is before my collective took the final descision of moving off google

Comment: and yes. we need high productivity, really fast engine, and alot of serious drawing and multimedia on top of all.